# Running a jar file in bluemix, inside a dialog app

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, executable-jar, watson-dialog

I'm currently trying to create an application like a Virtual Agent, using Watson Dialog. I have to use Node.js with this Watson service, but I have never used it before, so I took my time.
For now, I can use Java to call the dialog service to simulate an user. But I want to use Node.js to call Java to simulate the Agent.

In Watson Dialog, the Agent has a number of sentences written in a file like `dialog.xml`. But instead I want my Agent to ask specific questions according to the user's profile.

That's why I'm using a BRMS tool, written in Java. I created a `.jar` and want to call it in `/public/demo.js` to fill the variable `response`:

```
 var texts = dialog.conversation.response;
 var response = texts.join('<br/>');
```

I tried this in `/public/demo.js`:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('java -jar  C:\\PATH\\Example.jar',
    function (error, stdout, stderr){
        response += stdout;
        if(error !== null){
            console.log("Error -> "+error);
        }
});
```

Using that code in another application, it works without any problem, I can run my `.jar`. I'm sure of it. But once written in my Bluemix app, the first line make it crash. Am I missing something in the `manifest.yml` file? Do I need to change a config? Or maybe it comes from the `demo.js` file?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: The new Conversation service is easier to use, so you could try that. It will also have a REST API that should be simple to hook up to from Node.js.

Comment: I took a look, and tested it on my bluemix account. There's no difference, the REST API simulates the user, and I want to use my jar file to modify the Agent response. So it's not helping.

Comment: Bluemix gave me a response, it is impossible because of a docker thing. I will explore the two solutions they gave me. Having two app, one in Node.js and one in Java. Having the java version of Dialog. We'll see.